# how to make image1 show when div1 is clicked, image2 replaces image1 when div2 is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

HTML-

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="floatleft">
    <div class="JShover">
    <h3 class="border">Works with your business applications
    <p >Connect with Office 365, GSuite.</p></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="JShover">
    <h3 class="border">Works with your business applications
    <p>Connect with Office 365, GSuite, Zoho, Dropbox and many more to let your teams sign documents without
    having to switch between applications.</p></h3></div>
    </div>
    <div class="floatright" >
    <img class="integration" id="image1" src="integrations1-image.png" width="100%" height="auto">
    <img class="integration" id=iamge2" src="integrations2-image.png" width="100%" height="auto">       </div>
    <div style="clear: both;">
</div>
</div>
```

CSS-

```
.border{
  border-left:6px solid #3793EE;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 5%;
  }
div.JShover{
    height:50%;
    text-align: left;
    opacity:0.2; 
}
.wrap {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 700px;
}
.floatleft {
    float:left; 
    width: 50%;
    height: 500px;

}

.floatright {
    float: right;
    height: 500px;

   width: 50%;
}
```

JS-

```
<script>
    $(".JShover").click(function() {
    this.style.opacity = 1
        });
```

The images are in the same div. The text is however in different divs. I want to use JS so that when div1 is clicked show image1 and when div2 is clicked show image2. The text divs are in one container called floatleft and both the images are in floatright.
I have to give id's to both images, use visibility:hidden for images when text is not clicked. Unable to implement this in JS.

Comment: Is the question understandable guys?

Comment: what is div1 and div2 in this code

Comment: Div1 is the first JShover and Div2 is the second JShover. SHould i attach relevant id's to make it more understandable? code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/71973avt/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below. Comments below in code.

```
$(".JShover").click(function () {
    this.style.opacity = 1;
    $(".integration").hide();  //Hide all images
    //Only show the image related to the div "JShover" clicked
    $(".integration").eq($(this).index()).show(); 
});
```

```js
$(function () {
    $(".integration").hide(); //Hide all images

    $(".JShover").click(function () {
        $(".JShover").css('opacity', '0.2');
        this.style.opacity = 1;
        $(".integration").hide(); //Hide all images
        //Only show the image related to the div "JShover" clicked
        $(".integration").eq($(this).index()).show();
    });
});
```

```css
.border {
 border-left: 6px solid #3793EE;
 text-align: left;
 padding-left: 5%;
}

div.JShover {
 height: 50%;
 text-align: left;
 opacity: 0.2;
}

.wrap {
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: auto;
 max-width: 700px;
}

.floatleft {
 float: left;
 width: 50%;
 height: 500px;
}

.floatright {
 float: right;
 height: 500px;
 width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
 <div class="floatleft">
  <div class="JShover">
   <h3 class="border">Works with your business applications
    <p>Connect with Office 365, GSuite.</p>
   </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="JShover">
   <h3 class="border">Works with your business applications
    <p>Connect with Office 365, GSuite, Zoho, Dropbox and many more to let your teams sign documents without
     having to switch between applications.</p>
   </h3>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="floatright">
  <img class="integration" src="integrations1-image.png" width="100%" height="auto" alt="Image1">
  <img class="integration" src="integrations2-image.png " width="100% " height="auto"  alt="Image2">       
 </div>
 <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Should I implement the first JS and the second as well?

Comment: Hey @PhaniKumarM, in this code how do I make the opacity of the previously clicked div back to its previous opacity? I have tried adding different code to this but have not got it to work yet.

Comment: Updated code above. Just add this line `$(".JShover").css('opacity', '0.2');`

Comment: Awesome thank you. Where can I learn to make a good looking navigation bar at the top of the page, any suggestions? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have a look at bootstrap navbar - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#navbar. I would recommend this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$('#img_id').hide(); // to hide image
$('#img_id').show(); // to show image
```

So your code would be something like this

```
$('#div1').on('click', function(){
   $('#image2').hide(); // to hide image
   $('#image1').show(); // to show image
})

$('#div2').on('click', function(){
   $('#image1').hide(); // to hide image
   $('#image2').show(); // to show image
})
```

Comment: So I tried this, however when the page loads both images are seen, one below the other. They should ideally be in the same position and show only when the user clicks on the respective div. Your code did work partially, will update the question with this code. Anything else i could do?

Comment: If you want the images not to be displayed, add:

         <img class = "integration" id = "image1"
  __style = "display: none" __ src = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/578/578320.svg" width = "100%" height = "auto" style = "display: none">

Or better in css:

     .integration {
             display: none;
     }

Answer (score 1):

First of all you must check which `div` is clicked,getting its index using the [`index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) jQuery function:

```
 if($(this).index() == 0)
```

> Note that we start comptabilisation elements from `0` and not from `1`

after that you have just to select the relative `img` using the [`:eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/):

```
if($(this).index() == 0){
  $("img:eq(0)").show();
  $("img:eq(1)").hide();
}else{
  $("img:eq(0)").hide();
  $("img:eq(1)").show();
}
```

Finally, here is a DEMO:

```js
$(".JShover").on("click",function(){

if($(this).index() == 0){
  $("img:eq(0)").show();
  $("img:eq(1)").hide();
}else{
  $("img:eq(0)").hide();
  $("img:eq(1)").show();
}
});
```

```css
.border{
  border-left:6px solid #3793EE;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 5%;
  }
div.JShover{
    height:50%;
    text-align: left;
    opacity:0.2; 
}
.wrap {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 700px;
}
.floatleft {
    float:left; 
    width: 50%;
    height: 500px;

}

.floatright {
    float: right;
    height: 500px;

   width: 50%;
}

div.JShover:hover,.border:hover{
 opacity:1; 
 color:blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="floatleft">
    <div class="JShover">
    <h3 class="border">Works with your business applications
    <p >Connect with Office 365, GSuite.</p></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="JShover">
    <h3 class="border">Works with your business applications
    <p>Connect with Office 365, GSuite, Zoho, Dropbox and many more to let your teams sign documents without
    having to switch between applications.</p></h3></div>
    </div>
    <div class="floatright" >
    <img class="integration" id="image1" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/578/578320.svg" width="100%" height="auto" style="display:none">
    <img class="integration" id="iamge2" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/578/578457.svg" width="100%" height="auto" style="display:none">       </div>
    <div style="clear: both;">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is img:eq(0) exactly? Do i still need an id for the images?

Comment: @Yohanelly don't need an `id` ! ` img:eq(0)` means: SELECT THE `img` THAT HAVE THE INDEX `0`

Comment: Hi, i tried this but both images are not showing. https://jsfiddle.net/71973avt/3/

Comment: @Yohanelly I don't know why the images are not displayed in JSFIDDLE even if you remove the `style="display:none"`. But the code works fine here in code snippet

Comment: @Yohanelly I found it, your `src` link is wrong you can't access to a local file from JSFIDDLE !!!

Comment: @Yohanelly you must host your images to access to them !

Comment: Yes, But even when i run it locally on my system, the images do not show. I just copy pasted the code to JSFIDDLE so the src link is wrong. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Yohanelly there is certainly something wrong wit the `src` link, try to put a link of any shared image in google images & you'll see that's working fine. Good Luck

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156221/discussion-between-yohanelly-and-mehdi-bouzidi).